# Values error: Boolean types not allowed (at 'android:windowBackground' with value 'true')

Tags: android

I modified the values.xml files, and I accidentally put "true" in this part of code:

```
 <item name="android:windowBackground"> true </item>
```

I tried to change "true" to other variables, but always returns "true"

and this error:

> Error:(2002, 47) Boolean types not allowed (at 'android:windowBackground' with value 'true').
>
> Error:Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugResources'.
> com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: Failed to execute aapt

And the values.xml file is on ( /app/build/intermediates/res/merged/debug/values ) folder.

Sorry fo my bad Englih.

Comment: This information is insuffient. You have to provide full code and little more explanation as to when you are getting this error

Comment: Now? i try to remove the " true" variable but when i compile the app return "true" in the code.

Comment: one possible explanation is that you have multiple xml values file ...you have to delete it from all those

Comment: is only on this folder  /app/build/intermediates/res/merged/debug/values

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply modify the styles.xml file located in the path `app\src\main\res\values`

```
<item name="android:windowBackground">@color/red</item>
```

Something like above. Replace the red color with any preferable color of yours. Use the path I've mentioned above to modify the styles.xml file, the path you're pointing to is an intermediate build path and changes in that file won't affect your project because it is an auto generated file.

Answer (score 0):

1. Go to your `styles.xml` file located in `app/src/main/res/values` folder.
2. For item `android:windowBackground`, use a `color code` instead of value `true`. For example:

   ```
   <item name="android:windowBackground">#FF0000</item>
   ```
3. If `android:windowBackground` value `true` used in multiple `style.xml` then change their value to `color code`
4. Finally, `clean` and `build` your project again and `RUN` on your device